# Re-formatting bootable USB in Mac

Tags: usb-drive

I created a bootable USB for elementary OS 0.3.1. As you know, 0.3.1 brings some Grub problems, so I want to update to 0.3.2. But guess what? I can't use my USB at all. I created the bootable USB with "Create elementary OS Installer" for Mac. I'm running OSX El Capitan. How can I format my USB?

Answer (score 2):

I'm the author of that app. I've updated the app with a new build in tool for restoring USB drives on El Capitan. You can download the latest version [here](https://github.com/linusbobcat/create-elementary-os-installer/releases).